# Can't access rails server through local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, webserver

I start my ruby on rails server with:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

And from my local PC I can both access the server through http://localhost and http://192.168.0.101 (the localhost ip). But when I try to access it from a smartphone connected to the same wifi-network with the ip-address, nothing happens.

I am writing http://192.168.0.101 in the smartphone browser.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Stupid question, but needs to be asked:  are you 100% sure your phone is on the same network as your PC?

Comment: check your firewall if you sure it's connected to same network.

Comment: @maxwilliams yes i am sure, though I am both connected to an ethernet network and a wifi-network. I have tried, to disable my ethernet connection, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add, in an edit to your question, what you're typing into your phone browser's address bar?

Comment: My guess is your PC has a built-in firewall of some kind.

Comment: A firewall would make sence, I'll check up on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## I had the exact same problem and solve it!!

The problem was related to the windows firewall, when active it prevents local incomming conections without giving an alert or something.

### The solution

Open up the Firewall & network protection window and on **Private networ** turn of the private firewall.

**test and celebrate!!**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

run in terminal ipconfig(same for ubuntu and mac os). and there will be your network ip address. and you have to use your_ip_address:80 instead 0.0.0.0